Возможность обойти системную блокировку за некачественные вопросы. Может решим как быть?
Все мы знаем, что на SO есть система, которая "тайно" блокирует человеку (обычно новичку) возможность задавать новые вопросы, если он, скажем так, не привносит вклад в SO, не задает полезные вопросы и/или не отвечает на другие вопросы. Хорошо, теперь что обычно делают те, кто получил этот бан на возможность задавать вопросы?

Пытаются восстановить свою "репутацию".
Создают новый аккаунт и пишут с него очередные (часто бесполезные) вопросы.
Забивают на все и уходят с SO.

Первый пункт ок, молодцы. Последний, ну.. ладно, их выбор. А второй пункт является нарушением SO, из-за чего такие аккаунты вовсе удаляются, а основа может получить бан, все вроде логично и понятно. Но вот есть одно но... А как быть с теми, кто удаляет основной аккаунт (с блокировкой публикации сообщений) самостоятельно и сидит на "твине"?
Вот буквально пару часов назад я увидел человека, который явно с целью обхода блокировки создал 2-й аккаунт, а старый удалил. Была отправлена тревога, модератор 2-й акк забанил на 7 дней, но это разве решение? Цель блокировки задавать новые вопросы ведь в том, чтобы предотвратить дальнейшее распространение "бесполезных" вопросов на SO, чтобы человек хоть немного внес своего вклада в данный ресурс. А так получается каждый может создавать аккаунт, писать ерунду, получать бан публикации сообщений, удалять аккаунт, делать новой, получать там бан от модератора на неделю, после чего спокойно пользоваться ресурсом до очередного бана на вопросы? Если человек получает много блокировок, то он блокируется по IP системой, это я понимаю, мы с вами прекрасно понимаем и то, что это бесполезная механика, ибо у большинства IP динамичны, а в наше время так и вовсе, многие умеют использовать VPN...
Как выяснилось в комментариях, эта блокировка изначально идет тоже вроде как на IP
Собственно вопрос
Может я чего не понимаю и данное нарушение пресекается иными способами? Хотелось бы знать, как к такому относиться, имеет вообще смысл дальше отлавливать тогда таких нарушителей? Может тут стоит более строже относиться к этому, а именно, удалять новый аккаунт нарушителя? Правда не знаю, есть-ли у человека возможность восстановить старый аккаунт (вроде была), а то получится вечная блокировка уже.
В любом случае, ребят, 7 дней бана - это отличная лазейка для обхода блокировки публикации сообщений...

В комментариях подметили интересное сообщение от основателя SO, Джеффа Этвуда, где он говорит следующее: By the time this limiter reaches its threshold, they've had many chances to "get it right", and have consistently failed.. Другими словами, эта блокировка специально сделана такой строго, и сама компания не хочет вовсе видеть тех, кто не вносит вклад в SO, считая их нарушителями, которые не потрудились до блокировки сделать хоть что-то.
И тут опять вопрос про бан на 7 дней - господа, мы следуем поставленным правилам компании, основателей данного ресурса, которые против таких людей, они блокируют их по IP за такое, но вместо того, чтоб следовать этим правилам, мы поощряем явный обход этой системы. Я понимаю, что это может казаться слишком жестоко, но люди получают блокировку не просто так, людей зачастую предупреждают. Случай, о котором я написал выше, я там лично предупредил о возможности бана, наверно, на 3-м вопросе данного человека, спустя ~8 вопросов уже мелькал 2-й аккаунт, спустя ~10 вопросов он получил бан на основном, после чего удалил его. Это я к тому, что у человека было уйма времени, чтобы одуматься, понять, что-то исправить, но он проигнорировал это. Так может бан у него оправданный?
В любом случае, есть "закон" данной платформы - мы обязаны следовать им, особенно модераторы. Поэтому прошу, модераторы, обдумайте еще раз хорошо ваши наказании, как я и писал в комментариях, это похоже на то, что "пожизненно заключенный убийца нашел способ обмануть систему, чем он и воспользовался, обменяв пожизненное на 7 дней, спустя которые он выходит на свободу, вредит обществу до тех пор пока его не поймают, после опять меняет пожизненное на 7 дней, и так пока не надоест" - Звучит не очень, да? (утрирую специально!) Вот так это выглядит сейчас. Но ведь проще сказать "когда и если проблема станет массовой, ей и заниматься будут по-другому." или "раздувать из мухи слона" да? Я ведь просто прошу следовать поставленным стандартам чтоль.

Оставлю тут, как некое обновление информации.
Случай, который я тут затронул, получил продолжение: Человек создал 3-й аккаунт (как я и предполагал), но в этот раз, свой старый аккаунт удалять не стал (интересно, что было бы в этом случае). После жалобы, модераторы снесли этот аккаунт с его вопросом, а у старого обновили бан с недели до месяца, что уже вполне приемлемо я считаю  (спасибо вам за это, наконец, хоть что-то). Печальным остается тут то, что этот бан он получил всеж за создание отдельного аккаунта, а не за обход блокировки на вопросы, про нее походу все просто забыли и она ни как не влияет на срок или что-то еще. Зачем тогда существует система наказаний, на которую всем все равно?
Из этой ситуации можно вынести следующее:

Если аккаунт человека удален, то модерация не может его восстановить, а последующий созданный считается "основным" (что странно, ибо старые грехи забываются).
Всем все равно на блокировку возможности задавать вопросы, которую вешает система автоматически, включая модерацию. Точней не так, все равно на то, что эта блокировка вечная, требующая от нарушителя внесения вклада в SO, а это в свою очередь порождает странные действия по типу легких блокировок на неделю (обычно такой срок дают с целью успокоится). А это значит, что один будет неделями стараться набивать нужный рейтинг, чтобы снять это, а другой просто посидит в бане (если поймают) недельку и продолжит дальше, будто ничего не бывало.
По моим ощущениям, у модерации нету четкого регламента по которому они выдавали бы наказания, ибо данная ситуация показала то, что каждый модератор выбирает самостоятельно меру пресечения на свой вкус.
Если человек отсидит 7 дней, то дальше его трогать бесполезно, пока не нарушит что либо еще и/или не получит очередной бан на возможность задавать вопросы, ибо тут походу будет считаться, что он свое отсидел (внес так сказать своей "отсидкой" весомый вклад в базу SO...)

На этом пожалуй все, нужное для себя я узнал.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

@αλεχολυτ Ну давайте теперь я придерусь к словам... "Блокировка публикации сообщений" - каких сообщений? Комментариев? Может всеж оставим как есть, а не будем привносить свое... Пусть это будет "для красного словца" тогда уж. Если исправляете неточность, то сами будьте точны в выражениях. (комментарий удалите после прочтения)

Комментарий не является "сообщением" в терминологии SE. Сообщение (post) - это вопрос или ответ.  Таким образом формулировка "Блокировка публикации сообщений" корректна.

@αλεχολυτ Не согласен. У нас есть справка, и вон даже ваш ответ, где прямым текстом написано "бан вопросов". "Сообщение" для русского человека означает многое, в данном случае комментарии, вопросы, и т.д. Вы данной правкой только сильнее путаете людей.

У юзера, из-за которого родился этот пост была "блокировка вопросов", всё верно. Но для обсуждения ситуации это совершенно не важно. В частности поэтому оно объёдинено под одной меткой на MSE - post-ban. Блокировка, которая выдаётся участнику за плохие сообщения (вопросы/ответы), опубликованные ранее. Механизм одинаковый, затрагивать может либо вопросы, либо ответы, либо и то и другое.

@αλεχολυτ Вы изменили мой вопрос, в котором я затрагивал на данный момент только блокировку вопросов, вы это прекрасно поняли и в своем ответе дали ссылку на справку, которая на английском пишется как Question Bans, а переведено как Почему блокируются вопросы. В моем посту речь идет конкретно про вопросы. Я это назвал "теневой блокировкой", вам это не понравилось, ок, исправили, но суть не меняйте, я не говорил ничего про блокировку ответов, а также про блокировку комментариев (комментарий в русском, это тоже "сообщение").

И повторю, комментарии удалите, спор бессмысленный.

Восстановить удалённый аккаунт не представляется возможным. Об этом даже пишется на странице удаления профиля:

Удаление необратимо, у вас не будет возможности восстановить любые ваши данные, если удаление будет выполнено, и вы передумаете позже.

Но можно определённым образом (на уровне инструментов модератора) сопоставить новый аккаунт со старым. Конечно, никто не даст 100% гарантии, что новый аккаунт завёл действительно тот самый человек, что и удалил старый.
Бан публикации вопросов (за плохое качество ранее опубликованных) может снять с себя только сам участник, например, редактируя свои старые вопросы. Или даже публикуя полезные ответы. Точные критерии не раскрываются персоналом.
Если участник удалил учётку с активным баном публикации вопросов, то технически он уже никогда не сможет её снять. Что делать в этом случае, если регистрируется  новая учётка тем же самым человеком? Наверное, это должно зависеть от того, как быстро была заведена новая учётка после удаления старой. Например, если прошло достаточно времени (допустим, год), то можно просто считать, что это новый (другой) участник, не воспринимать это "обходом блокировки" и не предпринимать каких-то дополнительных действий на этот счёт.
Если же новый профиль появился практически сразу и продолжил публиковать вопросы, то мне кажется, как минимум нужно дать человеку понять проблему. Эту информацию можно, конечно, донести и комментарием под постом, но лучше использовать приватный канал "модераторы - участник". Что, собственно, и было сделано с выписыванием "бана". Возможно, срок блокировки в 7 дней и кажется небольшим, но в то же время я не вижу голосов "против" на парочке сообщений, созданных из-под новой учётки. Так же я не могу сказать, что было очень много заминусованных сообщений со старой учётки. Выглядит как какой-то пограничный случай. Именно поэтому наказание не такое суровое и посмотрим, как участник поведёт себя в дальнейшем.

Да, только это ведь не отменяет того, что через 7 дней человек опять продолжит бездумно задавать вопросы, через условно еще 7 дней получит опять "теневой бан", после чего ему ведь не запрещается проделать всею эту махинацию по новой (удалить аккаунт и создать новый). Поймите меня правильно, я не против этого человека, я его даже сам предупреждал про блокировку, сейчас речь, по сути, вообще не о конкретном человеке, а о системе в целом. Вот будет такой случай, когда условный "Вася" будет игнорировать все и создавать аккаунты по новой, что тогда?

@EvgeniyZ когда и если проблема станет массовой, ей и заниматься будут по-другому.

А вот это вот плохой ответ... У вас перед лицом прямое доказательство того, что систему обошли, а вместо того, чтоб это, не знаю, сообщить куда надо, либо придумать как за такое наказывать более адекватно, вы просто говорите "Ну как проблема станет массовой, тогда и подумаем". Ладно, в общем я понял, модерация бессильна и каждый может спокойно удалять старые аккаунты, сидеть в бане неделю и дальше спокойно сидеть без "теневого" бана. P.S. Посмотрите на плашку о блокировке в профиле у нарушителя, перевода не хватает.

@EvgeniyZ система не идеальна, однако это также не значит, что нужно раздувать из мухи слона и требовать "выслать пять мотоциклетов с пулемётами". Блокировка публикации придумана для уменьшения потока мусорных сообщений. Но если вопросы участника действительно такие плохие, то почему на них нет минусов хотя бы от вас?

Из мухи слона тут не делают, как и не просят вас "высылать модоциклетов". Я задал данный вопрос с целью обсуждения явной дыры на SO, недочета, бага, который просто нивелирует всю суть теневой блокировки. Я не пришел сюда наказывать кого либо, обсуждать конкретный случай, или действия модерации, я пришел именно с посылом "Вот дыра, давайте думать что с ней делать". Ну а в ответ мне говорят "Из мухи слона", а еще хуже "Ну, как будет побольше таких случаев, тогда и подумаем". Честно, мерзко такое даже видеть, лучше уж ответили бы банальным "Спасибо, я передам "руководству". ".

@EvgeniyZ если это предполагалось преподнести как баг-репорт, то стоило использовать другую метку [meta-tag:дефект], а не [meta-tag:обсуждение]. Мой ответ опубликован именно в контексте обсуждения как реагировать на это с точки зрения модерации сайта. Если оформлять это как баг, то рекомендую сразу писать на MSE, так как проблема затрагивает всю сеть, а не эксклюзивно ruSO.

А это уже вы расценивайте как полагается, баг, непроработанность мер наказаний, или что-то еще, я ведь не знаю всей вашей внутренней кухни, не знаю что у вас там за возможности и как все работает. Я вижу, как мне кажется, некую несправедливость, где одни восстанавливают неделями рейтинг, а другие просто сидят в бане недельку и после, я уверен, будут задавать опять подобные вопросы будто ничего и не было. И вместо того, чтоб начать в этом разбираться, может обсудить со своими коллегами, вы, увы, махнув рукой сказали мол "это норма, побольше случаев и начнем двигаться". Чтож, печально.

@EvgeniyZ недочета, бага, который просто нивелирует всю суть теневой блокировки. Судя по этим ответам (1, 2), истинная суть теневой блокировки — заставлять страдать пользователей в попытках избавиться от неё ¯\(ツ)/¯

@wololo Тогда надо вообще от не отказаться, раз только страдают, но это ведь сделать куда сложнее, чем модераторам подумать как правильней наказывать за такой обход данной системы. На данный момент, система есть, обходится элементарно, на что я жирно намекаю данным вопросом. Но увы, закрывают глаза и вообще "когда и если проблема станет массовой"... А ведь имеют доступ к чатам с КМ, другими модераторами, и т.д., ведь могут поднапрячься и придумать как в таких ситуациях дальше поступать. Наверно стоит всем новичкам советовать этот способ обхода, глядишь, "массовость" наберется)))

@EvgeniyZ Пройдите по ссылкам, почитайте. Товарищ, который судя по профилю раньше работал в компании, пишет, что плевать он хотел на попавших под теневую блокировку. Да, чисто технически, из под блокировки можно выбраться, «внося положительный вклад», но такой сценарий не предполагается основным.

@wololo И правда, извиняюсь, изначально не соизволил ознакомится со всем, что там. Интересный материал, оказывается эта блокировка еще и по IP идет сразу (если ничего не изменили с тех пор), а также, люди могут попробовать написать администрации и попросить пересмотреть решение блокировки (правда там речь была только про ошибочные баны). Но в целом да, такие люди для них это прям злостные нарушители. В целом, как я и сказал выше, я согласен с таким. Есть система, есть наказание - его надо соблюдать, а не делать полумеры, как сейчас вон блок аккаунта на 7 дней. Не мы ведь диктуем эти правила.

@wololo это не теневая блокировка (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Теневая_блокировка). Применяйте термин правильно пожалуйста :-)
